# Android Nested Fragment Approach

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am newbie in using android fragments .I got a scenario  Let me explain it  i got

1. Main Activity that extends **FragmentActivity**
    .My main activity consists of two **Fragments**
2. Option List That extends **Fragment**
3. Details List that extends **Fragment**
4. Details description that extends **Fragment**

When I launch my main activity . It will consist of Option List in **Fragment 1**  & Details List in **Fragment 2** . Then i select an item from Details List . Then its Description must be loaded into **Fragment 2** of the main activity

See this image

[image]

I am not getting an idea how to achieve this . I mean how can i tell Details List fragment to load Details description fragment inside main activity . Also when i press back button i must return to the initial stage ie

[image]

**EDIT :**

What i did was creating a interfaces(Listener) inside fragments and implement it on my parent activity. But if there is 10 different fragments i need implement all interfaces in my parent activity . So is there any other approach to achieve this??

Answer (score 4):

The thing to always remember when developing fragments is that it needs a UI in order for it to be displayed. You need a place in your layout where you want the fragment be. There are two ways of doing that:

- Create a Fragment class and declaring them in your layout like below.

  Here we assume that we have created a ArticleListFragment and ArticleReaderFragment fragment.

  ```
  <fragment
      android:id="@+id/list"
      android:name="com.example.news.ArticleListFragment"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1" />

  <fragment
      android:id="@+id/viewer"
      android:name="com.example.news.ArticleReaderFragment"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="2" />
  ```

  The downside of doing this is that you can't change this at runtime, meaning when your application is executing you can't replace a fragment with another one. If you have to display two fragments for example you have to declare two in your layout and hide either one. Fortunately there's another way.
- Programmatically adding your fragment at runtime. In this approach you have to declare a layout first and be sure to add a container (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc) where you will place the fragment. For example:

  ```
  <ListView
      android:id="@id/options_list"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1" >
  </ListView>

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@id/detail_layout"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="2"
      android:orientation="vertical" >
  </LinearLayout>
  ```

Here I define a list options_list for your options and a layout detail_layout where you need will put the details. Now at runtime when an option is clicked you display the details fragment on detail_layout like:

```
ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.detail_layout, fragment).commit();
```

To replace that fragment with another one:

```
Fragment newFragment = new AnotherExampleFragment();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.detail_layout, newFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Notice the call to addToBackStack. This is needed so that when the user presses Back, the previous one will be displayed.

I think you can figure it out from here. :)

Comment: actually i had gone through the article you mentioned . What i did was implementing interfaces in my Main activity to load Sub fragments. I want to know is there any better way to approach it . Do you need source code of what i have done??

Answer (score 0):

In Your Fragment Activity, you can use 2 containerviews (2 Linearlayouts for example) - for your left navigation (Option List) and your right content.
Then you need a public function like 
`public void switchFragmentInContainer(Fragment f, int position)`
in which you load a new fragment to your container...

In your OptionList, you call this function like 
`((FragmentActivity) getActivity).switchFragmentInContainer(NEWFRAGMENT, FragmentActivity.RIGHT);`.

I hope this is what you searched for.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding

```
// Create new fragment and transaction
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

You may also need:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ...
    public void onArticleSelected(Uri articleuri) {
        //use data to add the new fragment
    }
    ...
} 

public static class FragmentA extends ListFragment {
    OnArticleSelectedListener mListener;

    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnArticleSelectedListener {
        public void onArticleSelected(Uri articleUri);
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnArticleSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnArticleSelectedListener");
        }
    }
    ...

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Append the clicked item's row ID with the content provider Uri
        Uri noteUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ArticleColumns.CONTENT_URI, id);
        // Send the event and Uri to the host activity
        mListener.onArticleSelected(noteUri);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think this is from the article form developer blog. I had gone through that . What i did was implementing interfaces in my Main activity to load Sub fragments. I want to know is there any better way to approach it . Do you need source code of what i have done??

Comment: Code helps as I am not sure what you are asking. What I have given you is directly from developer.android.com the official documentation. If a fragment relates to this activity this is how you would load it. If a fragment doesn't relate to this activity then start a new activity.